# filtering search result when people type in search bar ( nothing happened )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement this, when people type in search bar, the search bar filter the result and fetch again from my api but in the console, I cannot see the new result or the new fetch.

Here is my code until now. I  do not know why search filtering not showing the result. I have to refresh the page until new results come.

what am I missing in my code?

```
const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  

const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/search?q=${value}`).then(res=>{
    console.log(res.data.posts);
    setData(res.data.posts)
    
  })

}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(data?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value,data]);

  return (
  <div>
    {
      data?.length > 0 && filteredPosts &&  
            <Postsabc  posts={data}   />
    }
  </div>)
};

export default Posts;
```

the value is changing when I look in the console. but the new search results are not showing until I refresh the page. I need help.

Comment: I think on second useEffect the data filter and filteredPosts remain empty. and the condition in return fails. Try to console the filteredPosts also.

Comment: @Developer it is an empty Array log(filteredPosts) . no , i think it is empty array

Comment: thats why  the condition is failed in the return and nothing render. Hope it will resolve the issue

Comment: @godwillhelpus I have update the code in answer. Try that

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call APIs directly in useEffect instead call a function and call your api in that function.
2. Make your second useEffect's dependency array only [value]

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
        const filteredData =  data?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
        setFilteredPosts(...filteredData)
      }, [value]);
   ```

Comment: what is number 2 ?  u mean i can not fix the search problem like this way ?

Comment: either you should show the data what's coming from your API as it is or just do local filtering, you are doing two thing at the same time, if you have a search api doing filter properly then remove second useEffect..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  

const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/search?q=${value}`).then(res=>{
    console.log(res.data.posts);
    setData(res.data.posts)
    
  })

}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(data?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [data]);

  return (
  <div>
    {
      data?.length > 0 && filteredPosts &&  
            <Postsabc  posts={data}   />
    }
  </div>)
};

export default Posts;
```

Also focused on filteredPosts, if it get empty then the div will not render.

Comment: why did you set the dependency array to [data]?

Comment: this code worked . but i do not know something wired happened . u have to press enter every time . another one every second it is fetching  that post untill now 5000 request

Comment: Is it sending request continuously?

Comment: yes it will cause you were haveing a dependency [data] for first one, now i think it should work.